# How can I apply jQuery to multiple class items children?

Tags: jquery, this, children, jquery-hover

I have a class called `.bxSlider`

I want to apply this jQuery to all the `.bxSlider` Div boxes. However, I want to apply some jQuery to individual boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // LOAD ITEM SLIDER
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager:false     
    });
    // BLACK IMAGE HOVERS
    $(".bxslider").hover(function() {
        $(this)(".bx-wrapper .bx-prev").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/left_arrow_off.png)");
        $(this)(".bx-wrapper .bx-next").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/right_arrow_off.png)");
    }, function() {
        $(this)(".bx-wrapper .bx-prev").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/left_arrow_on.png)");
        $(this)(".bx-wrapper .bx-next").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/right_arrow_on.png)");
    });
});
```

The HTML code, so you can see how I am using multiple boxes.

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="bxslider bx-wrapper">
        Hello <a class="bx-prev" href=""></a>
        Goodbye <a class="bx-next" href=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bxslider bx-wrapper">
        Hello <a class="bx-prev" href=""></a>
        Goodbye <a class="bx-next" href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using `this` but I cannot get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming .bx-prev is a child of .bxSlider ie:

```
<div class="bxSlider bx-wrapper">
  <div class="bx-prev"></div>
</div>
```

.

```
 $(this).find(".bx-prev").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/left_arrow_off.png)");
```

If you wanted to target a parent of .bx-slider then you can do:

```
$(this).closest("#desiredParentId").css("background-image", "url(//www.cdn.com/running/left_arrow_off.png)")
```

Comment: Perfect. Works very well. I like the `.find` solution and this. Thanks. Clean code too. I can learn and use this, never knew about that!

Comment: No probs. Glad I could help